# Writing Pandas DataFrame to Parquet file?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

I am reading data in chunks using pandas.read_sql and appending to parquet file
but get errors

Using pyarrow.parquet:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(query , conn, chunksize=10000):
    table_data = pa.Table.from_pandas(chunk)  #converting df to arrow
    pq.write_table(table=table_data,where=file.paraquet,
                   use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=True,
                   coerce_timestamps='ms',allow_truncated_timestamps=True)
```

Getting the following error:

```
  File "pyarrow\_parquet.pyx", line 1427, in pyarrow._parquet.ParquetWriter.__cinit__
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 120, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Unhandled type for Arrow to Parquet schema conversion: duration[ns]
```

using fast parquet:

```
from fastparquet import write
for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(query , conn, chunksize=10000):
    with open(os.path.join(download_location, file_name+ '.parquet'),mode="a+") as f:
        write(filename=f.name,data=chunk,append=True)
```

Getting following error:

```
    raise ValueError("Can't infer object conversion type: %s" % head)
ValueError: Can't infer object conversion type: 0    2021-09-06
```

Is there any solution which converts pandas dataframe to parquet file (append mode)
without datetime columns issue?

Comment: NB: *parquet. Not paraquet. It's right there in the module name.

Comment: You'll have to convert the duration type to something else. Perhaps an integer or floating point number, denoting the duration time in seconds or so. That depends on your precise problem.

Comment: @9769953 any help without converting column type?

Comment: What is the `dtypes` of your dataframe?

Comment: @9769953 duration[ns],timestamp[ns],string ,int64

Comment: What version of pyarrow are you on? (pa.__version__)

Comment: @Rok  pyarrow ==6.0.1 ,fastparquet == 0.7.2

Comment: Use astype('datetime64[ms]') on the erroneous column to convert nanoseconds to milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to convert the pandas dataframe chunk  into str
and write to parquet file

```
        query = f'select * from `{table["table_name"]}`'

        for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_sql_query(query , conn, chunksize=10000)):

            all_columns = list(chunk) # Creates list of all column headers
            chunk[all_columns] = chunk[all_columns].astype(str) 
            #convert data to string

            table_schema =chunk.dtypes.astype(str).to_dict()
            
            for k,v in table_schema.items():                
                if v == 'object':
                    table_schema[k]=pa.string()
            #create pyarrow schema for string format
            fields = [pa.field(x, y) for x, y in table_schema.items()]
            new_schema = pa.schema(fields)
            
            if i == 0:  
                pqwriter = pq.ParquetWriter(where=updated_path,schema=new_schema, compression='snappy')
                
            table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df=chunk, schema=new_schema,preserve_index=False,safe=False)
            pqwriter.write_table(table)
```